# docker can not write on mounted volume with non-root user

Tags: docker

I have Dockerfile with myuser from nginx image and I want to mount logs on mounted location, I am using docker-compose to start the container. My requirement is to use non-root user only and no sudo.

### My dockerfile with myuser, image tag I create is mynginx:v1

```
RUN addgroup mygroup
RUN adduser myuser --disabled-password
USER myuser
```

#### Non-Working docker compose with mynginx image with myuser

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: mynginx:v1
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - ./log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
```

Although directory get mounted, nginx log files access.log and error.log are not seen on host machine.

Docker logs gives below:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2021/04/09 12:46:08 [warn] 1#1: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
2021/04/09 12:46:08 [emerg] 1#1: mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

However If I do the same with official nginx image which runs as root user, things work correctly.

#### Working docker compose with official nginx image with root user

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - ./log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
```

Tried to look at various options but no luck so far.

Comment: Can you, outside of docker, write to that directory, using the same uid as the container user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most propably the UID on your host for `myuser` does not match the UID for `myuser` inside the Container.

## Solution

If you want to write from within your container into a directory of your host machine you must first create a `myuser` User on your host and check its UID via

```
$ sudo su - myuser -c "id"
uid=1000(myuser) gid=100(users) Gruppen=100(users)
```

In this example UID=1000 and GID=100.

Now you will need to create a Folder `~/log/nginx` with owner/group of `myuser` on your host.

```
$ sudo mkdir ~/log/nginx
$ sudo chown myuser ~/log/nginx
$ sudo chmod -R 0700 ~/log/nginx/
```

Afterwards you can create a Dockerfile and your user with the same UID/GID.

```
RUN useradd myuser -u 1000 -g 100 -m -s /bin/bash
USER myuser
```

Now you should be able to write to your mounted volume with the specified user. You can check this via:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx --rm -it mynginx:v1 /bin/bash
```

if you can now write to `/var/log/nginx`

Comment: Yes this seems to work, although official nginx image do not support non-root user and I had to make more changes to Dockerfile to make it work. Only thing I want to understand is about giving permissions on host machine folder, I dont see any other way than you mentioned (other than adding sudo in Dockerfile itself), any thoughts?

Comment: Another way could be to dynamically add your user and set the permissions (on Container startup) via a entrypoint script similar to the one used by the dockcross project. See: https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross/blob/master/imagefiles/entrypoint.sh

Comment: @Learner there is https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged

Comment: And how do I do that on windows?