# (GitHub Actions, Upload artifact) Access denied trying to upload a file despite giving it full permissions

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, permissions, github-actions

**Describe the problem**

I am making an action that runs API tests from a docker container, which generates a report.html. This report is saved into a docker volume.
Within the action, after the report is created, I attempt to use actions/upload-artifact on report.html, using the path to its place in the volume on the host machine.

The problem is I get `Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat /path/to/report.html` when the action attempts to do this.

I've tried to solve this by doing `sudo chmod ugo+rwx /path/to/report.html`  before using the action but it changed nothing. I think running the action with sudo would work but that doesn't seem to be supported.

**How to reproduce**

Reproducing an analogous example where I just create a test.txt file in the volume.
github action looks like this:

```
name: Action
on:
  push:
    
jobs:
  example:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Compose Containers and Run 
        run: |
          docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit
      
      - name: Fix permissions 
        run: |
          sudo chmod ugo+rwx /var/lib/docker/volumes/example_reports/_data/test.txt
        
      - name: Upload test.txt
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: test.txt
          path: /var/lib/docker/volumes/example_reports/_data/test.txt
```

Dockerfile is simply:

```
FROM ubuntu

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]
```

And doker compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  example:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - reports:/home/reports
    command: ["touch /home/reports/test.txt"]

volumes:
  reports:
```

Comment: Hey, from your description it's a bit difficult to guess what is going on. Also, it is generally not recommended to link to projects, but instead paste relevant snippets. Given the size of your reproducing example, it would be good to just copy some parts of it.

Comment: @rethab thanks for the advice. I attempted to clarify and moved the example out into (albeit rather large) snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was thinking about this too hard. All I needed to do to get upload-artifact to work was copy the file out of the volume directory first.

In the action file, instead of trying to fix permissions, simply do this after composing up the containers:

```
 - name: Copy out file from volume
   run: |
     sudo cp /var/lib/docker/volumes/example_reports/_data/test.txt /home/
  
  - name: Upload test.txt
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: test.txt
      path: /home/test.txt
```

Comment: If this resolved your problem, please accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark besides the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You're a genius!

Answer (score 0):

Your docker container is running as root and therefore creating the file as root.

You can change that by specifying

```yaml
    user: '1000:1000'
```

for your service in your docker-compose file.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing this won't allow me to write to the volume. However, there is a stackoverfow solution for writing to a volume as non-root, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020657/docker-can-not-write-on-mounted-volume-with-non-root-user 
I'll try these ideas out and see if they can help me.